# How to chain flows with different return types based on emitted values and collect their results?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have a situation where I have to execute 3 network requests one after the other collect their results (which are of different types).

Following is the relevant part of the code :

**Resource.kt**

```
sealed class Resource<T>(val data: T? = null, val message: String? = null) {
    class Loading<T>(data: T? = null): Resource<T>(data)
    class Success<T>(data: T?): Resource<T>(data)
    class Error<T>(message: String, data: T? = null): Resource<T>(data, message)
}
```

**Repository.kt**

```
override fun getReportData(profileId: Int): Flow<Resource<ProfileReport>> =
        flow {
            emit(Resource.Loading<ProfileReport>())

            var report: ProfileReport? = null
            try {
                // Api is available as a retrofit implementation
                report = api.getReport(profileId).toProfileReport()
            } catch (e: HttpException) {
                emit(
                    Resource.Error<ProfileReport>(
                        message = "An unknown http exception occured"
                    )
                )
            }

            if (report!= null) {
                emit(Resource.Success<ProfileReport>(data = report))
            }
        }
```

Say I have 3 such flows to fetch data in my repository and they have different return types (ex: ProfileReport, ProfileInfo, ProfileStatus).

Now in my viewmodel I have a function to execute these flows and perform actions on the values emitted such as :

**ViewModel.kt**

```
fun getProfileData(profileId: Int) {
        getReportData(profileId)
            .onEach { result ->
                when (result) {
                    is Resource.Loading -> {
                        _loading.value = true
                    }
                    is Resource.Error -> {
                        _loading.value = false
                        // UI event to display error snackbar
                    }
                    is Resource.Success -> {
                        _loading.value = false
                        if (result.data != null) {
                            _report.value = _report.value.copy(
                                // Use result here
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }
```

This works ok for one flow but how can I execute 3 flows one after the other.
That is, execute first one and if its successful, execute second one and so on, and if all of them are successful use the results.
I did it like this :

```
fun getProfileData(profileId: Int) {
        getReportData(profileId)
            .onEach { result1 ->
                when (result1) {
                    is Resource.Loading -> {/*do stuff*/}
                    is Resource.Error -> {/*do stuff*/}
                    is Resource.Success -> {
                        getProfileStatus(profileId)
                            .onEach { result2 ->
                                is Resource.Loading -> {/*do stuff*/}
                                is Resource.Error -> {/*do stuff*/}
                                is Resource.Success -> {
                                    getProfileInfo(profileId)
                                        .onEach { result3 ->
                                            is Resource.Loading -> {/*do stuff*/}
                                            is Resource.Error -> {/*do stuff*/}
                                            is Resource.Success -> {
                                                /*
                                                    Finally update viewmodel state
                                                    using result1, result2 and result3
                                                */
                                            }
                                        }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
                                }
                            }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
                        
                    }
                }
            }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }
```

But, this feels too cumbersome and probably there is a better way to chain flows based on success condition and collect results at the end. I checked some ways that use combine() or flatMapMerge() but was unable to use them in this situation.

Is there a way to achieve this? Or is this approach itself wrong from a design perspective maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this could be modeled much more cleanly using imperative coroutines than with flows. Since you're overriding functions, this depends on you being able to modify the supertype abstract function signatures.

This solution doesn't use `Resource.Loading`, so you should remove that to make smart casting easier.

```
suspend fun getReportData(profileId: Int): Resource<ProfileReport> =
    try {
        val report = api.getReport(profileId).toProfileReport()
        Resource.Success<ProfileReport>(data = report)
    } catch (e: HttpException) {
        Resource.Error<ProfileReport>(
            message = "An unknown http exception occured"
        )
    }

//.. similar for the other two functions that used to return flows.

fun getProfileData(profileId: Int) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        // do stuff to indicate 1st loading state
        
        when(val result = getReportData(profileId)) {
            Resource.Error<ProfileReport> -> {
                // do stuff for error state
                return@launch
            }
            Resource.Success<ProfileReport> -> {
                // do stuff with result
            }
        }

        // Since we returned when there was error, we know first 
        // result was successful.

        // do stuff to indicate 2nd loading state

        when(val result = getProfileStatus(profileId)) {
            Resource.Error<ProfileStatus> -> {
                // do stuff for error state
                return@launch
            }
            Resource.Success<ProfileStatus> -> {
                // do stuff with result
            }
        }

        // do stuff to indicate 3rd loading state

        when(val result = getProfileInfo(profileId)) {
            Resource.Error<ProfileInfo> -> {
                // do stuff for error state
                return@launch
            }
            Resource.Success<ProfileInfo> -> {
                // do stuff with result
            }
        }

    }
}
```

---

If you want to keep your current Flows, you could collect your flows this way to avoid the deep nesting. This works because your source flows are designed to be finite (they aren't repeatedly emitting new values indefinitely, but have only one final result).

```
fun getProfileData(profileId: Int) = viewModelScope.launch {
    var shouldBreak = false

    getReportData(profileId).collect { result ->
        when (result) { 
            is Resource.Loading -> { /*do stuff*/ }
            is Resource.Error -> {
                /*do stuff*/
                shouldBreak = true
            }
            is Resource.Success -> { /*do stuff*/ }
        }
    }

    if (shouldBreak) return@launch

    getProfileStatus(profileId).collect { result ->
        when (result) {
            is Resource.Loading -> { /*do stuff*/ }
            is Resource.Error -> {
                /*do stuff*/
                shouldBreak = true
            }
            is Resource.Success -> { /*do stuff*/ }
        }
    }

    if (shouldBreak) return@launch

    getProfileInfo(profileId).collect { result ->
        when (result) {
            is Resource.Loading -> { /*do stuff*/ }
            is Resource.Error -> { /*do stuff*/ }
            is Resource.Success -> { /*do stuff*/ }
        }
    }

}
```